# Google Apps Scripts for Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I tried to detect cell errors with the parameters being different cell formats, but what appears in the log is all the cells.

```
function detectError() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("RES2");
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange('D4:D301');
  var cellFormats = [];

  // get cell formats
  for (var i = 1; i <= range.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= range.getNumColumns(); j++) {
      var cell = range.getCell(i, j);
      var format = cell.getNumberFormat();
      cellFormats.push({ row: i + 3, col: j + 3, format: format }); // saving cell
    }
  }

  // checking differents formats on cells
  var uniqueFormats = Array.from(new Set(cellFormats.map(cell => cell.format)));
  Logger.log(uniqueFormats);
  if (uniqueFormats.length > 1) {
    Logger.log('There is different formats of cells.');

// showing different format of my cells
    for (var i = 0; i < cellFormats.length; i++) {
      if (countOccurrences(cellFormats, cellFormats[i].format) > 1) {
        Logger.log('Sel (' + cellFormats[i].row + ', ' + cellFormats[i].col + ') have different format ' + cellFormats[i].format);
      }
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('All cells have same format.');
  }
}
```

I also use count occurences

```
function countOccurrences(array, value) {
  return array.reduce((a, v) => (v.format === value ? a + 1 : a), 0);
}
```

the log should be showing just different cells format

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Getting cell formats:

```
function gettingCellFormats() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("RES2");
  const cellFormats = sh.getRange('D4:D301').getNumberFormats().flat();
  const uniqueFormats = [...new Set(cellFormats)];
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(uniqueFormats));
}
```